# Add SVN branch name on LaTeX title page

Tags: svn, latex

I want to have SVN branch name added (under the title) as sort of version information. I want it to be done automatically so that when I copy files generating the documentation to another (new) branch I get that info put in automatically. Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
So apparently svn package is needed (like `svn-multi`) for example and `xstring` package.

- First set keywords property on on your tex file:

  svn propset svn:keywords "URL Date Rev" >your_file<.tex
- Next add at the beginning of the .tex file:

  \svnidlong

  {$HeadURL$}

  {$LastChangedDate$}

  {$LastChangedRevision$}

  {$LastChangedBy$}
- Then in the document body add line similar to this (depending on what you want to extract)

  `\StrBetween{\svnmainurl}{branches/}{/sourcecode} \\`
- Last commit the .tex file to svn so the data gets filled in

And that's it!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at keyword substitution:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Edit:

Or alternatively you could use the `svn info` command to get the path from your working copy, write this to a file, read in the contents and parse using a regular expression. I'm assuming you have some sort of build process you use to generate the output document from the LaTeX source?

Also the posting here: http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2006/09/28/subversion-keywords-and-latex/ provides more information on doing what you want to do.

And here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svninfo

Comment: Thanks, but I looked at it earlier and I'm not sure it's so straight forward. What exactly I wanted to do is, say, we've got a svn url in this form http://subversion/project/branches/My_Working_Project_1.2/trunk/. So what I want to have in my latex-generated paper is My_Working_Project_1.2 or even better w/o underscores.

Comment: I guess then you'd have to write a script as part of your build process to parse the substituted keyword and pull out the parts you wanted. This would be fairly easy with REGEX I'm sure.